# Bootstrap scrollspy affect before section hit browser's top

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have bootstrap scrollspy perfectly works on my site, however I need some tweak because of this some issue :

my top menu (navbar) get hi-lighted when the section's div hit the browser top visible area. precisely.

but, since my top menu is floating, how to get this scrollspy effect works 50 pixel BEFORE that section's div hit the browser top visible area.

here's my jquery :

```
<script>
    $('body').scrollspy({ target: '#top-menu' });
</script>
```

thank you

Comment: Use the [offset](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy-options) option.

Answer (score 1):

Use the offset option

```
<script>
    $('body').scrollspy({ target: '#top-menu', offset: 50 });
</script>
```